# Battery replacement for 16 VAC

Tags: power, batteries, ac, adapter

I have a mains power adapter that powers a small model train set. I would like the option to power this off a rechargeable battery, although I'm not sure this is possible, as it uses AC.

My current power adapter reads: SEC.: 16.0 VAC 0.75 A Max 12.0 W

Can anyone recommend how to get this power output from a smallish battery?

The transformer came with a single track controller. The controller outputs 12 VDC at 0.75 A.

Comment: It's doable - a 12W inverter is possible, and 16V isn't high. The design is not simple for someone new to electroncis though, and I'm not sure you'd find a system off the shelf which would do the job. 12W out of battery isn't too hard, but does mean a pretty beefy battery if you want it to run flat out for hours. But I have more questions for you: What frequency is your AC? How small is "smallish"? How long will this be running for? Why are you looking at using a battery? Are you sure you really need AC for a train set?

Comment: Are you sure the AC doesnt' get rectified to DC at some point in the train set? That would make it easier, if it does.

Comment: How many hours run-time do you hope to get? Do you have the capability to measure the actual power draw you have for typical use? Your train set may not use anywhere near the maximum. The easiest way might be to measure on the plug side with a *kill-a-watt* or similar device.

Comment: Can you edit your questions to describe the speed controller?  If it can take a Either AC or DC input then you might be able to use a battery .

Comment: Agree that your best bet is to find out if AC is really needed or if you can make DC work instead.

Comment: Hi all, Thanks for coments: I will try to get a different contorller fo the train, as yes, the controller that I currently have converts to DC anyway, so I should be able to find one that accepts DC in. 
My current one is: gaugemaster single track controller, output 12v DC 0.75amp.

Comment: @PatrickGoddard You could also consider modifying the controller to add a DC input. Depending on how the controller is designed, it could be as simple as just drilling a hole for the plug, and soldering a couple of wires. (Or it might not be that simple. You might have to add a switch to select whether it uses AC or DC power)

Comment: What make and gauge are the locomotives. Only a couple of brands use AC (eg Marklin). Others use DC.

Comment: Start with a modest size 12 V rechargeable battery. Simplest may be one of the all-in-one power stations sold everywhere, but a small 7 Ah lead acid battery will be fine too. You should have a 5 A fuse for safety. Then scratch on ebay/amazon/etc for a "buck converter", at least 3 amp rating, with a human finger adjustable knob on the front (not a screwdriver potentiometer). There are quite nice ones with voltage and current meters. Finally you need a reversing switch, made from a DPDT (6 terminal) switch. This system will provide the 0-12 V DC you need on the track.

Comment: @tomnexus The suggeston is that he needs AC. Some model trains do. Some dont

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach (but not the cheapest) if AC is really required is to obtain a low wattage 12VDC to AC mains inverter and then use it to drive a mains to 16V (or similar) transformer.

If you really need AC then there are numerous DIY 12 VDC to 50 Hz AC circuits available. Most of these are intended to provide 230 VAC or 110 VAC output, but by use of an appropriate transformer you can obtain lower voltages.

There are [many examples here](https://www.google.com/search?q=diy+12v+to+mains+inverter&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&sxsrf=ALiCzsYxO-YcI5fdQB4pW7AwZLSdbc3XaA:1664360665049&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBpN_Rorf6AhWM4DgGHSTgBEUQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=2340&bih=1153&dpr=1.75) - this is an image serach with each image linking to a website.

[Here](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fhow2electronics.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2019%2F08%2F12V-to-220V-Inverter.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fhow2electronics.com%2F12v-dc-to-220v-ac-inverter-circuit%2F&tbnid=HRjbW28cW6Pz_M&vet=12ahUKEwicgMLaorf6AhUgjtgFHRZrDFcQMygFegUIARD2Ag..i&docid=qas9HSoAD0Kw9M&w=1280&h=686&q=diy%2012v%20to%20mains%20inverter&ved=2ahUKEwicgMLaorf6AhUgjtgFHRZrDFcQMygFegUIARD2Ag) are links to 12 circuits, all of which appear potentially suitable.

[Here](https://how2electronics.com/12v-dc-to-220v-ac-inverter-circuit/) is a single example which I chose for the low component count and reasonable oscillator circuit. The transformer could probably be a 24V centre tapped (for input) and 12V winding for output. Possibly using just a 24V centre tapped winding or two x 12V windings for the oscillator and taking the output off the transistor drains would work.

[image]